# Do ETFs issue their own 1099 forms?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, form-1099

I, this year, traded some ETFs that track US stock market indices; like SPY, QQQ, DIA. Do these ETFs issue their own 1099 forms for reporting Gains/Losses, or are those ETF transactions just reported on the 1099-B from the brokerage firm like other individual stocks? ( I'm using Fidelity)

Comment: I buy Black Rock ETFs from Fidelity, but Fidelity issues the 1099, not Black Rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Fidelity as well, and they issue a consolidated 1099, which includes the 1099-B, for my ETF transactions.

Answer (score -2):

Gains and losses from the sale of ETF shares are reported on Form 1099-B issued by your broker.

How the gains (or losses) are taxed depends on the type of ETF.

EDIT

I surmise that the taxation comment is the reason for the down votes. Just in case you're not familiar with this, ETFs involved in currencies, futures, and metals are sectors that receive different tax treatment. Google for details.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suspect the downvotes are because you didn't answer the question asked, which (as I read it) is about **who issues** the 1099, not which type of 1099 is issued.

Comment: I suspect that you're right.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The other answer is more relevant but I still appreciate your answer.